# ¿Cómo obtener años actuales en una consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera que me puedan ayudar. Lo que quiero hacer es que me muestre todo los años actuales, estoy realizando con **SQL SERVER**

Es decir, yo voy a tener una variable como está donde voy indicar el año que voy a parametrizar:

```
Declare @AñoInicio varchar(4)
SET @AñoInicio='2019'
```

Es decir que si el año actual es la fecha es 2019 que solo se muestre así:

```
2019
```

Pero si en caso estamos en el año 2020 se muestre así:

```
2019
2020
```

y si ya es el año 2025 se debe mostrar así :

```
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
```

He estado buscando alguna forma pero no me sale. ¿Me podrian ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: puedes explicar qué es lo que quieres que se muestre así?, el resultado de un select?, tienes fechas en una tabla?

Comment: @Lamak lo que yo quiero mostrar es decir si yo tengo un año parametrizado y ya estamos en el año 2020 en un select se muestre el año 2019 y el 2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si bien no me queda 100% claro, creo que lo que necesitas es algo como esto:

```
DECLARE @AñoInicio int;
SET @AñoInicio = 1981;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,number,CAST(@AñoInicio as varchar(4)) + '0101') Fecha
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
    AND DATEADD(YEAR,number,CAST(@AñoInicio as varchar(4)) + '0101') <= GETDATE()
)
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Fecha) Año
FROM CTE
;
```

El resultado es:

```
╔══════╗
║ Año  ║
╠══════╣
║ 1981 ║
║ 1982 ║
║ 1983 ║
║ 1984 ║
║ 1985 ║
║ 1986 ║
║ 1987 ║
║ 1988 ║
║ 1989 ║
║ 1990 ║
║ 1991 ║
║ 1992 ║
║ 1993 ║
║ 1994 ║
║ 1995 ║
║ 1996 ║
║ 1997 ║
║ 1998 ║
║ 1999 ║
║ 2000 ║
║ 2001 ║
║ 2002 ║
║ 2003 ║
║ 2004 ║
║ 2005 ║
║ 2006 ║
║ 2007 ║
║ 2008 ║
║ 2009 ║
║ 2010 ║
║ 2011 ║
║ 2012 ║
║ 2013 ║
║ 2014 ║
║ 2015 ║
║ 2016 ║
║ 2017 ║
║ 2018 ║
║ 2019 ║
╚══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes generar unos cuantos números consecutivos y hacer aritmética simple, sin necesidad de aritmética de fechas, para obtener los años desde el inicial hasta el actual, sin sobrecargar el motor.

Un ejemplo, que soporta hasta 100 años, podría ser:

```
declare @AnioInicio int = 2010;

with
   e1 as (select x from (values (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null)) q(x))
,  e2 as (select a.x from e1 a cross join e1 b)
, Num(n) as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) from e2)
select @AnioInicio + Num.n - 1 Anio
  from Num
 where @AnioInicio + Num.n - 1 <= year(getdate());
```

Que al ejecutarlo en el 2019, nos devuelve:

```
Anio
--------------------
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019

(10 rows affected)
```

Si llegarás a necesitar soporte para más de 100 años, puedes añadir un nivel más al generador del consecutivo, y tendrás hasta 10K años:

```
declare @AnioInicio int = 2010;

with
   e1 as (select x from (values (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null), (null)) q(x))
,  e2 as (select a.x from e1 a cross join e1 b)
,  e4 as (select a.x from e2 a cross join e2 b)
, Num(n) as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) from e4)
select @AnioInicio + Num.n - 1 Anio
  from Num
 where @AnioInicio + Num.n - 1 <= year(getdate());
```